# How can I make Apache Zeppelin/Shiro work on a different port (not 8080)?

Tags: port, apache-zeppelin, shiro

Apache Zeppelin 0.9.0 preview1 including basic Shiro auth works fine as long zeppelin.server.port specified in conf/zeppelin-site.xml is 8080. However, I would like to use another port (e.g. 9000) for my zeppelin site (experimental localhost setup). When I change the port in zeppelin-site.xml, Shiro auth is no longer possible: the small indicator to the left of the "Login" button on the Zeppelin welcome/login screen is no longer green, but red and login is not executed no matter what credentials I enter.

I did not find any hint on the Shiro website; could anybody kindly give me an idea what could be wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Feel free to open JIRA for that issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN

Comment: Apache Shiro is just an application security framework and does not open any ports by itself. Did you create an issue at apache zeppelin yet?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem: Port `9000`

In a project, I encountered the same problem. We used the environment variable `ZEPPELIN_PORT` to set the Zeppelin port to `9000`. According to the [Apache Zeppelin documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/setup/operation/configuration.html#zeppelin-properties), this is the same setting as your `zeppelin.server.port` in `zeppelin-site.xml`. Using port `9000`, for me the login did not work anymore and the login indicator became red instead of green.

### Fix

Setting the port to some other value than `9000`, for example `9090`, fixed this problem.

The Zeppelin [documentation of `ZEPPELIN_PORT`](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/setup/operation/configuration.html#zeppelin-properties) mentions:

> Zeppelin server port
>
> Note: Please make sure you're not using the same port with Zeppelin web application development port (default: 9000).

I could not find anything about changing this Zeppelin web application development port. But apparently some check of the Zeppelin login routine renders the login unusable if one tries to set port `9000` as `ZEPPELIN_PORT`. So just pick another port number and it should work.